# Table data not showing in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
public function displayallquestionsandoptions() {
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->library('table');
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT QuestionId,Name,SurveyId,CreatedOn from question");
  $table = $this->table->generate($query);
  return $table; //Added this
}
```

Calling in another function:

```
$questionstable = $this->displayallquestionsandoptions();
$this->load->view('questions', $questionstable);
```

VIEW CODE:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Question Id</th>
    <th>Question Name</th>
    <th>Survey Id</th>
    <th>Created On</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($questionstable as $questionrow) ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $questionrow -> QuestionId;?></td>
        <td><?php $questionrow ->Name;?></td>
        <td><?php $questionrow ->SurveyId;?></td>
        <td><?php $questionrow ->CreatedOn;?></td>
      </tr>
    <?phpendforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**I am unable to access the array variable please help someone do i need a model can i work without it?**

Comment: Why you put ; just after return statement in return; $table;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
return $table; //good
```

and not

```
return; $table; //bad
```

You don't need the `;` after `return` unless you want to return nothing.

In your calling function, do this too:

```
$questionstable['dataquestions'] = $this->displayallquestionsandoptions();
$this->load->view('questions', $questionstable);
```

You're referring to `$dataquestions` in your view, but that variable doesn't exist.

Also, in your `foreach`, you're missing the `:` at the end.

It should be:

```
foreach($dataquestions as $questionsrow):
```

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() i still get this issue

Comment: Do what I said about `questionstable['dataquestions']` and then call `$dataquestions` in the foreach :) @vini

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: OK try  `$questionsrow['QuestionId'];`. @vini

Comment: I am getting empty values though i have data

Comment: OK, change `return $table;` to `return $query;`. Then use `foreach($dataquestions->result() as $questionsrow):`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

In Controller return the query object

```
public function displayallquestionsandoptions() {
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->library('table');
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT QuestionId,Name,SurveyId,CreatedOn from question");
  return $query; //Added this
}
```

In other function, try like

```
$data['questionstable'] = $this->displayallquestionsandoptions();
$this->load->view('questions', $data);
```

and in view fetch details like

```
<?php foreach ($questionstable->result() as $questionrow) ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $questionrow -> QuestionId;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $questionrow ->Name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $questionrow ->SurveyId;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $questionrow ->CreatedOn;?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to write little code:Change below line with your line in public function `displayallquestionsandoptions() {}` method

```
$table = $query->result_array();
```

and little change In your calling another function line...

```
$data['questionstable'] = $this->displayallquestionsandoptions();
$this->load->view('questions', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
first load this

```
$this->load->library('table');

public function displayallquestionsandoptions() {
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->library('table');
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT QuestionId,Name,SurveyId,CreatedOn from question");
  return $query->result_array();
}

$questionstable = $this->displayallquestionsandoptions();
$this->load->view('questions', $questionstable);
```

in view just use this

```
echo $this->table->generate($questionstable);
```

no foreach needed for more info check this 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html